# Equivalent of "svn revert" or "git checkout --" in Bitkeeper

Tags: bitkeeper

If I modify a file, and then do not need this changes. How can I go back to the original state of the file. I mean modifications made locally that are not checked in or committed or pushed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the command line:

```
bk unedit file
```

Or run bk citool and pick the Discard button.